# Update a running container - Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have a running container that I want to update, due to some parameters that I add on docker-compose.

tried docker-compose up -d, but didn't work (complains about having the same port).

any solutions or do I have to remove and re-add the container?

Comment: If you edit the `docker-compose.yml` file and re-run `docker-compose up -d`, it will recreate anything that's changed.  How did you start the container originally?

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker-compose restart` or `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`.
The first command simply restarts the container with your new settings.
The second command deletes the old container and creates a new one also with your new settings.

Comment: docker-compose restart would be nice 'cause then I didn't have to delete the container, but it's complaining with error: "No containers to restart" even though the container is running.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding -p [PROJECT NAME] to the docker-compose up